# Camera button is not displayed while capturing photo WinPhone, Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am facing an issue with Xamarin media plugin xam.plugin.media framework version 2.6.1 (the issue persists with previous versions as well)
While taking photo using media plugin in Xamarin for WinPhone 8 development, the camera capture button is not displayed. The button is still there, we can tap there and capture the photo. When we touch in the bottom space, the camera button is being visible.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after lot of search and finally learnt that the issue was with the requesttheme was light in the native app's App.xml in WinPhone project. Once I removed `RequestTheme="Light"`, the problem fixed and the camera button is displayed.